# Error when launching thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

When I launch thunderbird I get the following error message:

```
elias@eliasc:/usr/lib/vmware-installer/3.0.0/cdsHelper/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0$ thunderbird
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/thunderbird/libmozgtk.so:
libgio-2.0.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object
Couldn't load XPCOM.

elias@eliasc:/usr/lib/vmware-installer/3.0.0/cdsHelper/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0$ ldd /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd99bd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f702f49b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f702f494000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f702f27b000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f702f12d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f702f112000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f702ef26000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f702f5a1000)
elias@eliasc:/usr/lib/vmware-installer/3.0.0/cdsHelper/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0$ ldd /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0e2db000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f21dfe37000)
    libldap60.so => not found
    libprldap60.so => not found
    libmozsandbox.so => not found
    liblgpllibs.so => not found
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f21dfcde000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f21dfcaa000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0x00007f21dfc7b000)
    libmozsqlite3.so => not found
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so (0x00007f21dfc16000)
    libmozgtk.so => not found
    libmozwayland.so => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f21dfc0d000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f21dfc08000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f21dfc01000)
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f21dfbc1000)
    libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f21dfbb5000)
    libicui18n.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67 (0x00007f21df8ad000)
    libicuuc.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67 (0x00007f21df6c4000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f21df6a8000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f21df55a000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21df36e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f21e660a000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f21df2ab000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f21df261000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f21df256000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f21df249000)
    libevent-2.1.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7 (0x00007f21df1f3000)
    libvpx.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.6 (0x00007f21defd5000)
    libdbus-glib-1.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2 (0x00007f21defaa000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f21def53000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f21deef8000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f21dedc2000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f21ded6f000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f21ded45000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f21ded39000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f21dec0f000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f21debe8000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f21de817000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f21de812000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f21de80d000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f21de7e3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f21de69e000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f21de689000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f21de470000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f21de455000)
    libicudata.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67 (0x00007f21dc93c000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f21dc8ff000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f21dc8f1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f21dc8c2000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f21dc8b9000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f21dc804000)
    libffi.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f21dc7f6000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f21dc780000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f21dc764000)
    libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f21dc759000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f21dc671000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f21dc5c5000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f21dc5b6000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f21dc5b0000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f21dc584000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f21dc569000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f21dc561000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f21dc559000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f21dc536000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f21dc50e000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f21dc433000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f21dc40e000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f21dc2ee000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f21dc2e4000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f21dc2b7000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f21dc220000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f21dc206000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f21dc1de000)
    libmd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f21dc1d1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

running in terminal `echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was empty.

then `sudo medit ~/.bashrc` or with your prefered text editor

then at the end of file add:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/thunderbird/:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

and finally `source ~/.bashrc`

Note in that specific case help to found which libraries thunderbird could not locate, using: `ldd /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird`
`ldd /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so`

eg. output `libbsd.so.0 => missing`
then I checked where these missing libraries were located with
`locate library_xxxx` in terminal